# How do I make a macro that understands a row is highlighted on different tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if this is possible - basically, I have an Excel workbook with several tabs, each with an amortization schedule for  payments collected. When a payment comes in, I go to the tab, select the row for that month's payment, and highlight it green to indicate it's been collected. Once we have over 25 or so different payments coming in, it will be tedious to go through the workbook tab by tab manually highlighting that month's payment. I'm wondering how I would create a button that would basically just say "Everyone paid this month," for instance, and clicking it runs a macro that highlights the row below the lowest highlighted row on each worksheet.

I have tried creating the macro, but since the payments are at different points in the life of the repayment, it's not as simple as just having it always highlight "Row 10" for instance then "Row 11" the next month - I need it to find the lowest highlighted row, then highlight the next row. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Possibly using `Range.Find`.

Comment: Excel can't read colours, only data. So instead of colouring your cells, add a helper column, fill it with data, and create some conditional formatting rules for handling the colouring.

Answer (score 1):

- Locate the last colored row and set hightlight on next row

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HightlightRow()
    Dim c As Range, Sht As Worksheet, iRow As Long
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = vbGreen ' modify as needed
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        Set c = Sht.Cells.Find(What:="", After:=Sht.Range("A1"), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=True)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            iRow = 2  ' the first data row, skip header
        Else
            iRow = c.Row + 1 ' next row
        End If
        Set c = Application.Intersect(Sht.Rows(iRow), Sht.UsedRange)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a legend of statuses= colors in first line: Cell A1 - payment done,B1-payment not done etc.
Then you pick the range by macro and check if all the cells of the range are highlighted in a color you need as this:

```
Sub Check_Payments()
Dim StatusColour as Variant, count1 as Long, sRange as Range, count as Long
StatusColour=Cells(1,1).Interior.Color'pick the status color from the legend 
Set sRange=ActiveSheet.Range(<range need to check, for example"A2:A10">) 
count1=0
count=0
For Each x in sRange
count=count+1
If x.Interior.Color=StatusColour Then count1=count1+1'check if the highlight of the cell is the status color
Next x
If count1=count1 Then MsgBox "All paid" Else MsgBox "Some assholes didn't pay"
End Sub
```